# Why does the Ħaġar Qim seem to have drilled holes / pitted dots on its stoneworks?

Tags: archaeology, prehistory, building, malta

Does anyone have any idea or knowledge why Neolithic temple stones have these small holes? They are facing the sun, and the other side of the stones is flat. Smaller object were drilled all over, not just on one side. I saw these in Ħaġar Qim, Malta:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Such stippling is a common feature at prehistoric Maltese sites. They are often considered a primitive decorative pattern - somewhat of a forerunner of a [modern art form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointillism).

> It is the best preserved of all the Maltese temples ... The two left-hand lobed chambers are linked by a trilith niche of **stones decorated by stippling**; the inner of these two chambers is subdivided and in it stands two betyls, or pillar altars.
>
> **<sub>- Service, Alastair and Bradbery, Jean. *Megaliths and Their Mysteries: A Guide to the Standing Stones of Europe.* MacMillan Publishing Co.: New York. 1979</sub>**

And:

> The device of stippling the background with an infinitude of tiny hammer-pick holes exquisitely sets off the boldly rounded curves that seem to have been a happy obsession with these artist-masons.
>
> **<sub>- Hogg, Garry. Malta: Blue-water Island. AS Barnes, 1968.</sub>**

However there is no real way to be sure about their purpose. Some suggests, for instance, that [a row of the dots counted the number of days between equinoxes](http://www.wondermondo.com/Countries/E/Small/Malta/Mnajdra.htm).

Comment: Is some stones one can see "counted" dots. But drilled holes on figures fills totally the surface of the stone. Hard to think they are counted, but has anyone tried?

Comment: @MarkokraM I'm not saying they are counts of things. Like I said, the most likely, and the most popular, explanation is still they are just a decorative pattern. I was just making a point on how it's not really possible to know why someone who left no records made such marks.

Comment: So if no knowledge, how about ideas, just wild guesses?

Comment: I ran across the equinox counting paper also, and had the thought that maybe the decorative patterns were there to conceal the functional patterns.  But the real answer is "there is no real way to be sure about their purpose". +1

Comment: @MarkokraM I'm not really sure what you're asking. We do have some ideas for what they might be, and I listed two in my answer.

Comment: Ideas about the meaning. Happy obsession or pattern arent meanings. Decorative, yeah. These are just too obvious, just a description what we see, not ideas what they might have meant or developed from.

Comment: @MarkokraM You can't really demand that simple engraved patterns must necessarily have any meaning beyond "it's decorative". I'm sorry that my answer is more mundane than you'd like, but an answer is no less true for being boring.

Comment: I actuallu can. And I think you have to if you want to research the topic. "We cant really know" is a real show stopper. Maybe this is the reason that those drills have never been investigated. But sure I dont demand epistemic irreputable answer, I was just asking and wondering. I saw sea shells on the natural museum of Malta which had exactly the same decoration, drill holes. Could be the source for imitation and later obsession?

Comment: Then what is hypothesis and theory? You have to have some ideas what to look and see if there is enought weight from evidences. "You cant know" is the worst hypothesis, or conclusion if you will, to test.

Comment: @MarkokraM A *hypothesis* is falsifiable. By demanding that there must be deeper meaning to these patterns, you have developed a *conclusion*.   A hypothesis is not the same thing as a conclusion. Moreover, "we can't know for sure" is a perfectly legitimate conclusion to draw when there is no evidence. How can you possibly know what people who lived 5000 years ago were thinking? Just because you don't like the facts doesn't make them "the worst".

Comment: Well leys say that stating drills are a happy obsession and decoration, it doesnt seem very scientific either. Its just circular statement and impossible to falcify. Who would know its done happily or obsessively? Its a lot of pits, which any eye can see. But I can accept its a decoration if thats best science and human mind can do. I like it simple anyway.

Comment: @MarkokraM That phrase simply means the prehistoric Maltese appears to have been fond of such patterns. That's an objectively verifiable fact.

Comment: But there is hardly need for science for such statement?

Comment: Sorry from my part also, I was just in a mood of small debate and critics. Nothing personal.

Answer (score 0):

It is a decorative pattern. Artists call this kind of stippled background pattern a *ground*. In Japan it is known as *nanako*, which means fish eggs. The purpose is to set off and accentuate the primary design.

Comment: In pillars they just used background pattern, but nothing on it? In those cases it should be called just a pattern. Or was it was a background for sun light rays? Then why such background? Maybe answer is really easy if we could see how sun light behaves on stone blocks...